# Php how to get alternative week dates

Tags: php, date

I want to display the alternative week dates for the current month. Suppose today is Wednesday of the week. So i want to display date from Monday to Friday of this week. I want the same for the next next week(skip one week). So i want

- 6th Jan to 11th Jan
- 20th Jan to 24th Jan

or

- 13th Jan to 18th Jan
- 27th Jan to 31st Jan (alternative week)

(These dates are described in Context of 2014)

Comment: so you are trying to get 6 day weeks and skip a day?

Comment: yes. 5 days a week. for month Jan 2014. i want to display 6th Jan to 10th Jan, 20th Jan to 24th Jan dates. i want to display Alternative weeks from the current date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime();


echo $date->format('dS M'); // today
echo "<br />";

$date->modify('this week'); // reset to firstday of the week, Monday
echo $date->format('dS M');
echo "<br />";

$date->modify('+1 day'); // add 1 day with current stored date
echo $date->format('dS M');
echo "<br />";

$date->modify('next week'); // go to next week
$date->modify('next week'); // doing this second time will add another week
echo $date->format('dS M'); // print first day of that week
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/86141)